# cleancss command not working

Tags: npm, npm-install, clean-css

I installed clean-css locally but my npm script is throwing an error because cleancss is not found (`sh: cleancss: command not found`).
I tried running cleancss straight from the command line and installed it globally (`npm install -g clean-css`) but my shell still doesn't know about it. All other packages are working fine.
Here's what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "echo '=> linting' && jshint **/*.js",
    "minify:js": "echo '=> minify:js' && uglifyjs main.js -o public/js/main.min.js",
    "minify": "echo '=> minify:css' && cleancss main.css -o public/css/main.min.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-css": "^4.0.2",
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.5"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks @RyanZim, I updated my question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [clean-css docs](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#important-40-breaking-changes):

> clean-css 4.0 introduces some breaking changes:
>
> - API and CLI interfaces are split, so API stays in this repository while CLI moves to [clean-css-cli](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css-cli);

You have only the API installed. You need to install the CLI. Run:

```
npm install --save-dev clean-css-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev clean-css
```

To uninstall the API-only version and install the CLI.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: For Sublime Text, the _Minify_ package stopped minifying CSS files because it could not find the `clean-css\bin\cleancss`. After reading your answer, I just tried `npm install -g clean-css-cli` and the reference seems to have been automatically fixed. It works, thanks!

Comment: npm i -g clean-css-cli